# How to extract "type" - Email or Web from an Outlook Email using VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried to extract the data from an Outlook email using VBA:

```vb
Sub DLPExtract()
    
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As MailItem
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("gfdo@aviva.com\Inbox")
    
    i = 1
    
    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        If InStr(OutlookMail.Subject, "Data Loss Prevention Report: GFDO DLP Daily Report Retrospective") > 0 And OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
        
            Range("Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Date
            Range("Type").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.
            Range("Reference").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ID
            Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
            
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next OutlookMail
    
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I want to extract only IDs in the fourth column but first need to check if that is already in the respective column on Excel sheet. If yes, do nothing and If no, then take that ID out from this fourth column in email and paste it in respective column on Excel sheet.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything, that hasn't worked?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem  may expose some ideas for you.  I can't replicate without receiving any myself.  Also, may be best to hide the email address in here too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to check the email body format.

If that is the case then follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat) which talks about the "Bodyformat" property.

```
Range("Type").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.BodyFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what "Type" property you are interested in - the Outlook object model doesn't provide the `Type` property for their items. Instead, you may be interested in the [MessageClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.messageclass) property which returns or sets a string representing the message class for the Outlook item. The `MessageClass` property links the item to the form on which it is based. When an item is selected, Outlook uses the message class to locate the form and expose its properties, such as Reply commands.

Also you may be interested in the [BodyFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bodyformat) property which returns or sets an [OlBodyFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olbodyformat) constant indicating the format of the body text. The body text format determines the standard used to display the text of the message. Microsoft Outlook provides three body text format options: Plain Text, Rich Text (RTF), and HTML.

Finally, there is no need to iterate over all items in the folder and checking whether they correspond to the predefined condition:

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If InStr(OutlookMail.Subject, "Data Loss Prevention Report: GFDO DLP Daily Report Retrospective") > 0 And OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
```

Instead, I'd recommend using the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)